# How can I define this code so that it can return true when it comes to Palindrome?

Tags: java

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String s){
   for(int i = 0;i< s.length();i++ ) {
       if(s.charAt(i)==s.reverse)
   }
}
```

How to complete this to accomplish this goal?

Comment: @jgr208 That's not valid junit for anything I've ever seen...

Comment: thought so, since i didnt see any assert true or anything like that

Comment: @jgr208 Not only that, but junit only allows for void return functions with no arguments.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for asking people to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is this?

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can reverse strings using StringBuilder, so this could be more easy written as

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString().equals(s);
}
```

Comment: The for loop needs to be s.length()/2

Comment: why using StringBuilder tho?

Comment: You use `StringBuilder` because it has a built in `reverse` method that will reverse the order of the String. And when reading the code, it is much easier to follow and understand what is happening.